# Alternative/More efficient method than self joins hive queries

Tags: database, hadoop, hive, self-join

I have a hadoop table described below:

```
mappers
id (int)
mapper (String)
mapperid (int)
date (int)
```

Some samples rows would be as below

```
1, MAP1, 123, 20140810
1, MAP2, 3421, 20140810
2, MAP1, 34211, 20140810
2, MAP3, 1143, 20140810
3, MAP4, 12, 20140810
```

I am attempting to condense these results to unique IDs and mapperIds associated with them.
I expect my query to return based on the sample data above:

```
1, 123, 3421, null
2, 34211, null, 1143
```

Below is my hive query where I am basically grabbing ALL the data I want and them compounding the data on itself where applicable, unfortunately this requires 4 table look ups.

```
select distinct 
full.id, 
mapper01.mapperid, 
mapper02.mapperid, 
mapper03.mapperid 
FROM mappers as full
LEFT JOIN (
    select id, mapperid FROM mappers
    WHERE mapper = "MAP1" AND
    date = 20140810 AND
    length(id) > 0
) AS mapper01 ON mapper01.id = full.id
LEFT JOIN (
    select id, mapperid FROM mappers
    WHERE mapper = "MAP2" AND
    date = 20140810 AND
    length(id) > 0
) AS mapper02 ON mapper02.id = full.id
LEFT JOIN (
    select id, mapperid FROM mappers
WHERE mapper = "MAP3" AND
    date = 20140810 AND
    length(id) > 0
) AS mapper03 ON mapper03.id = full.id
WHERE date = 20140810 AND
length(id) > 0 AND
(full.mapper = "MAP1" OR
full.mapper = "MAP2" OR
full.mapper = "MAP3"
);
```

I am contemplating using FULL OUTER JOINs instead of LEFT JOINS, this way I would only require 3 table lookups (The most outer grab all data would be redundant) and using some IF Logic to grab the full.id from one of the tables that has that info.

However I was wondering if there was a better approach than using joins.

Comment: Did you try to use Pig?

Answer (score 0):

I've written a blog posting on how to use the Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ) 'collect' UDF to solve this problem. ( http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-collect-to-avoid-the-self-join/ ).

Instead of doing self joins, which in Hadoop ends up with multiple scans of the data, use a collect to group the data into a single map. Then access the elements you want from that map using the 'map_index' UDF.  Your query would be something like this :

```
SELECT ID, MAP_INDEX( id_map, 'MAP1' ) as MAP1_ID,
           MAP_INDEX( id_map, 'MAP2' ) as MAP2_ID,
           MAP_INDEX( id_map, 'MAP3' ) as MAP3_ID
 FROM 
   ( SELECT id, COLLECT( mapper, mapperid) as id_map
      FROM mappers
      WHERE  date = 20140810 
       AND  length(id) > 0
     GROUP BY id
   ) m ;
```